# how to correct first battery discharge for smartphone

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, smartphone

I would like to know how to take corrective action on the first charge cycle.
I have just bought a new smartphone and completely discharged before full charging. However i just came across articles which say that i need to first charge to 100% and then discharge completely. 
I have done the other way and it says it would damage the battery. 
By the time i tried to put to charge, it was almost drained. How do i take corrective action?

Answer (score 0):

I read about, that the modern batteries nowadays don't need this action to be done. Because battery has limited lifetime because of the charging circles that it can stand. so if you charge to 100 then discharge then again to 100 that's 1,5 circle, but if you discarge first and then charge full it's 1 circle.
But today's batteries have a very big number of expected circles. So it's not really needed.